# If I have 'allow apps to request to track' on, does the developer still get access to the data listed under app privacy?

Tags: privacy

Under 'app privacy' the data that is listed such as location or identifiers which is under data used to track you, is that still available to the developer if l have allow 'apps to request to track' switched on and l decline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data listed under "App Privacy" is a declaration from the developer to you as the user which types of data they used to track and, and which data they link to you. It is however not a technical or functional specification of features unlocked for you or the developer, and as such do not represent any kind of "blocking" or "system denial" of information made available to the developer.

So this means that for example if the developer has specified that they link "Location" to you, it doesn't say anything about whether or not iOS makes location information available to the app. You'll see a separate prompt asking letting you decide whether or not the app will get information from iOS about your location (mainly from the built-in GPS). You can change whether or not the app gets that information from System Settings.

However even if you do not give that permission to the app, the app might still know your location by other means. I.e. for example by extracting location information from your photos, by deriving location information from your IP address, or many other means. The App Privacy declaration is there so that the developer is obligated to inform you whether or not they track you or link you by location by any means.

Note that it is possible for developers to lie or give incorrect information in the App Privacy section. However, if they do, it would certainly give Apple the possibility to remove the app from the App Store if they so choose, and possibly, depending on your jurisdiction, you might have the grounds for a lawsuit.